# Wont let me download pip, says there's a permission problem and I need to update pip

Tags: python, pip

```
Audreys-computer:~ audreyoneill$ python3 -m pip install pyautogui
Collecting pyautogui
Collecting pyobjc-core; platform_system == "Darwin" (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/89/3eaee8bb68a0c97264b247e17d5ed3d3b28c231c398ff7ca68114267e44a/pyobjc_core-6.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from pyautogui)
Collecting pyobjc; platform_system == "Darwin" (from pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/20/5c04da2ff530575cb33189ce4d2caeb6a6f1a225e16d5d7786422e789091/pyobjc-6.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pymsgbox (from pyautogui)
Collecting pyscreeze>=0.1.21 (from pyautogui)
Collecting mouseinfo (from pyautogui)
Collecting pygetwindow>=0.0.5 (from pyautogui)
Collecting pyobjc-framework-ContactsUI==6.2; platform_release >= "15.0" (from pyobjc; platform_system == "Darwin"->pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/73/abbe22cd58de044a79e74ac2d5d0a0f77935d25e42ba1940283b67e0c549/pyobjc_framework_ContactsUI-6.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting pyobjc-framework-LinkPresentation==6.2; platform_release >= "19.0" (from pyobjc; platform_system == "Darwin"->pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/b2/62b31931d71fc02cffe3f160b16be6bd0b904009afd4c310b478e17d96de/pyobjc_framework_LinkPresentation-6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyobjc-framework-GameplayKit==6.2; platform_release >= "15.0" (from pyobjc; platform_system == "Darwin"->pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/74/68adcd6f7ca37822174911996c3cce611a68708c4716bf7301a9e3cd5076/pyobjc_framework_GameplayKit-6.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AutomaticAssessmentConfiguration==6.2; platform_release >= "19.0" (from pyobjc; platform_system == "Darwin"->pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/ec/05bfda63334fef86a98cfa4ce6d39516d442f89d48d5c2be2b11f309151e/pyobjc_framework_AutomaticAssessmentConfiguration-6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==6.2; platform_release >= "10.0" (from pyobjc; platform_system == "Darwin"->pyautogui)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/60/3a2684462d76e6202e68fea22cfb80ac99abbd9185eceec331ad2bcedb62/pyobjc_framework_AppleScriptObjC-6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==6.2 (from pyobjc; platform_sysNotificationCenter, pyobjc-framework-MapKit, pyobjc-framework-Network, pyobjc-framework-iTunesLibrary, pyobjc-framework-CoreHaptics, pyobjc-framework-PhotosUI, pyobjc-framework-FinderSync, pyobjc-framework-DiscRecordingUI, pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit, pyobjc-framework-Collaboration, pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes, pyobjc-framework-SceneKit, pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling, pyobjc-framework-MediaPlayer, pyobjc-framework-Social, pyobjc-framework-ColorSync, pyobjc-framework-PushKit, pyobjc-framework-ModelIO, pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices, pyobjc-framework-AVKit, pyobjc-framework-AuthenticationServices, pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices, pyobjc-framework-ExternalAccessory, pyobjc-framework-VideoSubscriberAccount, pyobjc-framework-GameCenter, pyobjc-framework-SoundAnalysis, pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage, pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge, pyobjc-framework-StoreKit, pyobjc-framework-CalendarStore, pyobjc-framework-Automator, pyobjc-framework-Vision, pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN, pyobjc-framework-NetworkExtension, pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping, pyobjc-framework-SearchKit, pyobjc-framework-BusinessChat, pyobjc-framework-CoreMediaIO, pyobjc-framework-LocalAuthentication, pyobjc-framework-CoreMotion, pyobjc, pymsgbox, Pillow, pyscreeze, rubicon-objc, pyperclip, mouseinfo, pyrect, pygetwindow, pyautogui
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/pyobjc_core-6.2-py3.7-nspkg.pth'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.1b1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Have you trieud running the suggested command `pip install --upgrade pip` ? (you may need to do `pip3 install --upgrade pip` instead)

Comment: You probably need to run using `sudo`.

Comment: it is hard drive (file system ) permission error i guess. just go to /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/pyobjc_core-6.2-py3.7-nspkg.pth and enable all file permissions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+EnvironmentError+Errno+13+Permission+denied

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you do not have permissions to write to that system folder. Try installing to the user folder with this command:

```
python3 -m pip install --user pyautogui
```